# Adding Android support to GLFW

Tags: android, glfw

This might sound like a really wild question, but its one that I've been toying around with lately. If I wanted to add Android support to GLFW, so that GLFW could run on Android, how should I proceed? Which is the best way to get started?

Comment: Reference to existing thread: https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/611

Comment: some guy has done it now

Comment: use sdl http://libsdl.org/